# Escaping built-in WP function return strings

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, security, escaping

Should one filter the output of builtin WP functions such as `get_permalink()` and well-known WP plugins such as ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) such as `get_field()`?

For instance `get_permalink()` calls `home_url()` which calls `get_home_url()`, **none of which do any filtering of the data**. In a similar fashion work `the_content()`, `the_title()` and the rest of the familiar Loop-related functions.

Therefore, is the following sufficient? (*no `esc_attr()` for WP and ACF functions*)

```
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts() && __return_true($wp_query->the_post()) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?=get_the_permalink()?>">
        <img src="<?=get_field('homepage_thumbnail')['sizes']['thumbnail']?>" />
    </a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Or should I be more careful with the data coming from the plugin? (*notice `esc_attr()` added to ACF image source, third line*)

```
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts() && __return_true($wp_query->the_post()) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?=get_the_permalink()?>">
        <img src="<?=esc_attr(get_field('homepage_thumbnail')['sizes']['thumbnail']?>)" />
    </a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Or should I be super careful even with the stock WP functions? (*notice `esc_attr()` added to WP anchor href, second line*)

```
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts() && __return_true($wp_query->the_post()) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?=esc_attr(get_the_permalink())?>">
        <img src="<?=esc_attr(get_field('homepage_thumbnail')['sizes']['thumbnail']?>)" />
    </a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping is used to produce valid HTML or other formats, and it depends on context.

Escaping a url in something like `<a href="<?php echo $url?>"....` is needed in order to replace any "&" characters with & (although browsers will most likely fix it for you if you don't do it).

Escaping a url in an input element like `<input value="<?php echo $url?>"...`do not require replacement of "&" but do require replacement of any quote character.

So in general, since escaping is context sensitive you can assume that wordpress API will not escape it for you. What plugins do, is up to the plugin itself.

Answer (score 3):

You should always escape your data, whatever its origin. For your example, the URLs should be escaped using [`esc_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url).

WordPress has many functions which can be used. There's an article on [Data validation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) on the Codex which lists the various functions available.

Comment: It seems that some functions, such as `the_title()` and `the_content()` are [not to be escaped](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52597/should-i-escape-wordpress-functions-like-the-title-the-excerpt-the-content?rq=1).

Comment: You can't apply escaping to functions that starts with `the_` since they already echo the value. Yes, from the link you posted, it is said that you don't need to `esc_html()` the value of `get_the_title()`. But you might want to escape it with `the_title_attribute()` or even `esc_attribute` if you're using the post title as an attribute in your HTML.